# What's the quickest way to unlock a Sith, a Bounty Hunter and a small character in LEGO Star Wars: The Complete Saga?

Tags: lego-star-wars

When playing a new game of LEGO Star Wars: The Complete Saga, what are the quickest routes (i.e. smallest number of Story Mode episodes required) to unlock a Sith, a Bounty Hunter and a small character so they can be used in Free Play levels?

Comment: Not sure if it is the same, but in the original LEGO Star Wars II, the quickest way to get a dark Jedi was to create a custom character with a red lightsaber.

Comment: @JasonBerkan I tried, but it doesn't work for The Complete Saga. Only Star Wars II.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a list of all the characters and how to unlock them on [this page](http://swgames.wikia.com/wiki/LEGO_Star_Wars:_The_Complete_Saga_Characters).

I've done what I can to find the "easiest" of each class, although they're a little poorly organized, so this might not be the most optimal path.

- The only story-unlock Sith is Darth Vader, who you can unlock after Ep. 6 level 5.  Your other Sith options are pretty expensive unlocks.
- Wicket unlocks after Ep. 6 level 4.  I believe he(?) counts as a small character.
- There are no bounty hunters unlocked from story missions as far as I can tell, but Bib Fortuna is available for purchase for 16,000 studs after Ep. 6 level 1.

From this, I'd probably clear Episode 6 first, and work towards 16k studs to get Bib Fortuna.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Wicket does indeed count as a small character. I forgot to ask about Stormtroopers too, but that's an easy answer: they can either be bought for 10,000 studs after Ep. 4 level 1, or if you don't like spending them you can wait until you have Darth Vader from your route above, as he can open all Stormtrooper doors.

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest completing Ep. 1  chapter 5 and completing this unlocks a small character (Anakin skywalker/boy) also do Ep. 1  chapter 6 and this unlocks darth maul

Comment: According to the accepted answer, the only sith to unlock via playing the story is Darth Vader.  You also don't mention anything about a bounty hunter.  Can you expand on your answer?